# ORA-01422 in simple function - why too many rows?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a table

```
pricehist (product_id INTEGER,
           price FLOAT,
           valid_from DATE,
           valid_until DATE);
```

which lists how much a product costed/costs at a specific time. 
I want my function to return the difference to the previous price:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION difference (prod_id IN NUMBER, val_from IN DATE) 
RETURN NUMBER AS 
 p_old NUMBER;
 p_new NUMBER;
BEGIN
 SELECT price INTO p_old FROM pricehist WHERE product_id = prod_id AND valid_until = val_from - 1;
 SELECT price INTO p_new FROM pricehist WHERE product_id = prod_id AND valid_from = val_from;
RETURN (p_new - p_old);
END difference;
```

I tried to

```
SELECT product_id, price, valid_from, difference(product_id, valid_from) FROM pricehist
```

but I get

> 01422.00000 -  "exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows" 
>   *Cause:    The number specified in exact fetch is less than the rows returned. 
>   *Action:   Rewrite the query or change number of rows requested

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that both queries produce a single row?

Comment: To debug, you should simply execute one of your queries with the parameters you are passing to see if multiple rows are being returned. This error comes when your query is returning multiple rows!

Comment: Well yes, they should. There are no duplicates.. although pricehist doesn't have any UNIQUEs.. may that be the problem?

Comment: Aha, solved.

I tried the same thing again on a similar table with contraints UNIQUE(product_id, valid_from), UNIQUE(product_id, valid_until) and it worked.

Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause for ORA-01422 is that a one-row result was expected and the query returned several rows.

In your case, it happens because one of your queries is returning several rows. You should redefine your `WHERE` conditions to ensure that only one row is returned.

An alternative is to get only the first result, for example, using `ROWNUM <= 1`

With this, your queries shoul look like:

```
SELECT price INTO p_old
  FROM pricehist 
 WHERE product_id = prod_id 
   AND valid_until = val_from - 1
   AND ROWNUM <=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can even skip the function completly with this query:

```
SELECT product_id, price, valid_from, 
    price - LAG(price, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY product_id ORDER BY valid_from) AS difference
FROM pricehist
```